# Rebuild Solr index in a specific Search node

Tags: solr, datastax-enterprise

I've accidentally cancelled the Solr index build in one my Search nodes. How do I restart the indexing on that node?

*nodetool rebuild_index* doesn't work. The command exits almost immediately - probably because it is meant to work with native Cassandra indexes whereas my table's indexes are of custom type "com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.Cql3SolrSecondaryIndex"

Clicking the "Reindex"/"Full reindex" button in the Solr core admin UI, on the other hand, will trigger the re-indexing of the whole columnfamily across all Search nodes.

Is there a way to trigger the indexing in that node only? I'm using DSE 4.0.1 (Cassandra 2.0.5, Solr 4.6.0.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to reindex a single node, you have to reload its core with the reindex=true and distributed=false parameters, as explained in: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.0/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchReldCore.html